# Online SVN tools?

Tags: svn, remote-access

I am developing a project with distributed team, For this i am looking for some online tool which helps in maintaining versions of data.
More Specifically i need check in and check out facility so that only a single person can work on a single file at a time.

Before this all of us resides in single building and are connected through Intranet and there we use Microsoft Visual Safe Source, so in simple words i need some online tool that provide more or the same functionality as MS VSS provides. My preference is to go for some open source tools.

Comment: " i need check in and check out facility so that only a single person can work on a single file at a time." - that's a bit backward: I say embrace merge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svn has more or less been superceded by distributed source control systems like Mercurial and Git. Check out [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org) (based on Mercurial) or [Github](http://github.com) (Git).  Either will do what you need, and be a lot nicer to use than VSS or SVN. [**edit**] apart from the oldschool VSS style single user check out/check in thing.  Are you sure you *need* that?

Answer (score 1):

[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/) are fast becoming the SCC of choice.

I still use Subversion (via [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/)) at home. Subversion can be configured for [remote access](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#paranoid)

[Subversion on Windows with Remote Access](http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Subversion-on-Windows-with-Remote-Access.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The workflow you're thinking of is provided by Subversion. A [google search](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=subversion%20hosting) will find many online subversion hosters.

While distributed version control offers more facilities, it won't provide the kind of workflow you're used to and therefore take longer for you to learn.